# Edit list based on a mapping data frame

Tags: r, mapping

I want to edit a list `l` based on a mapping data frame `mapping`

```
mapping = data.frame(german=c("Hund", "Katze", "Vogel", "Schwein"),
                     english=c("dog", "cat", "bird", "pig"))

l = c("Katze", "Schwein", "Kuh", "Hund", "Vogel")
```

My desired result would look like this

```
l = c("cat", "pig", NA, "dog", "bird")
```

It is required that the order in `l` will be conserved. Moreover the computational time must be kept to a minimum since `l` has about 20 000 elements.

Anyone an idea how to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance,

Christian

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We can use `match`

```
with(mapping, as.character(english)[match(l, german)])
#[1] "cat"  "pig"  NA     "dog"  "bird"
```